# 400 Bad Request in GitLab's Mattermost

Tags: nginx, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, mattermost

GitLab 8.9.4 running fine (Omnibus) in an Ubuntu Server 16.04 virtual machine through port 802:
`external_url 'http://gitlab_url:802'`

I've enabled Mattermost by this line in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:
`mattermost_external_url 'http://gitlab_url:8065'`

I've also opened the port 8065 in my router.
But this is what I get when I try to access that gitlab_url:8065 in a browser:

> 400 Bad Request
>   Request Header Or Cookie Too Large
>   nginx

In the [guide](http://doc.gitlab.com/omnibus/gitlab-mattermost/), I skipped the "Running GitLab Mattermost on its own server" part because it would be fine for me with the embedded version if I could make it work.

Reading the "Manually (re)authorising GitLab Mattermost with GitLab" part, I went to the `Applications` section in the `Admin Area`, and I found a "Mattermost" application.
The two urls there were wrong (probably because the first time I set a dummy `mattermost_external_url`), so I manually corrected them. I'm not sure if I tried with/without the port or both.

I tried to remove Mattermost Application in GitLab and start again Mattermost configuration. I also tried to reset Mattermost (doing [this](http://forum.mattermost.org/t/resetting-gitlab-omnibus-mattermost-installation/464/5)) but I always get to the same error.

I also tried to set this in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```
mattermost['gitlab_enable'] = true
mattermost['gitlab_secret'] = "***"
mattermost['gitlab_id'] = "***"
mattermost['gitlab_scope'] = ""
mattermost['gitlab_auth_endpoint'] = "http://gitlab_url:8065/oauth/authorize"
mattermost['gitlab_token_endpoint'] = "http://gitlab_url:8065/oauth/token"
mattermost['gitlab_user_api_endpoint'] = "http://gitlab_url:8065/api/v3/user"
```

---

I enabled the log:
`mattermost['log_file_directory'] = '/var/log/gitlab/mattermost'`

And `cat /var/log/gitlab/mattermost/mattermost.log` basically tells me:

> Automatic database upgrade failed.!!!

But this is the first time I try to set up Mattermost!

Also note everytime I run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` (and I called it after every modification) I get a laaarge output.

(I posted the same question [here](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/400-bad-request-in-mattermost/3573?u=norike))

Comment: There is an open bug regarding this at [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1872)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DJ Mountney](https://gitlab.com/twk3) gave the answer [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1872#note_29156814):

> The Mattermost service runs by default on port 8065 (behind nginx),
>   the mattermost external url setting is telling nginx what port to
>   listen on for mattermost.
>
> If you set the two to the same port, only one will get it. In your
>   case it was nginx, if you run sudo gitlab-ctl tail mattermost you will
>   likely see that it has failed to bind to the port.
>
> If you change the mattermost_external_url to a different port, it
>   should start working.

Indeed, changing mattermost port solves it. Ie:

```
mattermost_external_url 'http://gitlab_url:8066'
```

Also note `gitlab_auth_endpoint`, `gitlab_token_endpoint` and `gitlab_user_api_endpoint` urls should point to the gitlab application + port (`802` in my case, not `8066`):

```
mattermost['gitlab_auth_endpoint'] = "http://gitlab_url:802/oauth/authorize"
mattermost['gitlab_token_endpoint'] = "http://gitlab_url:802/oauth/token"
mattermost['gitlab_user_api_endpoint'] = "http://gitlab_url:802/api/v3/user"
```

Comment: +1 because you pointed me to "sudo gitlab-ctl tail mattermost". In it I found that I have an issue with "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" error, because of the newly installed SSL cert. Apparently, Gitlab/Mattermost didnt trust my new certificate and it was fixed by copying the PEM file into the /etc/gitlab/trusted-cert